# How to Improve the Responsiveness of Inline Keyboards

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I've recently been working on a Telegram bot for automating data entry on a particularly annoying spreadsheet that some of my friends just don't like interacting with. So I thought I'd make them a nice telegram bot, so we can all push data to the spreadsheet without actually using the spreadsheet. Pretty simple.

However, and sure enough, they say they find it very cumbersome to use because the Inline Keyboards I've used to keep some inputs standard are a bit sluggish; especially when tabbing through pages or using some simple "widgets" I've built to input dates. Here's how they look:

[image: Simple Inline Keyboard for selecting my friend's names]

and

[image: Simple Inline Keyboard for selecting a date]

The part they complain about is that when tabbing through the names, or when going up and down on those "selection wheels" (if you can call them that) to pick dates, they can handle the first few inputs just fine, but after about the fourth or fifth input in a row the Keyboard simply stops responding for a brief moment, resuming updates after about 1 sec.

I've profiled my code already and the classes for managing the Inline Keyboards (which are quite lightweight) are absolutely fast enough to handle more than 5 inputs in a row, and my Heroku logs seem to indicate that the slugging part are the webhook updates themselves! It's as if Telegram itself was deliberately stopping fast inputs, although I've found no mention in the documentation to whether this is the case or not.

At any rate, I'd like to ask you guys if you've faced the same issue in the past and, in that case, what did you do to improve / work around the situation? The bot works excellently *except* for the responsiveness on the Inline Keyboards and it's kind of killing me not being able to find a way of making them faster.

Any and all help will be appreciated! <3

Comment: I'm experiencing the same with my own bots and have yet to disvover any other bot which doesn't have this behavior. Considering the various known [tg limits](https://limits.tginfo.me/en) I'm pretty certain it is intended and unfortunately there is really nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Your bot works on webhooks? Consider calling `getUpdates` yourself so you can 'get the button press' faster than Telegram send you the webhook.

Comment: Using `getUpdates` while using the webhook approach is impossible. As per the Telegram Bot API Documentation: "There are two mutually exclusive ways of receiving updates for your bot — the getUpdates method on one hand and Webhooks on the other"

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I ment in stead off using webhook, I'd recommend *switching* to `getUpdates` so you can lower the poll interval.

Comment: Can you paste some code